# how to get custom results using spring data jpa using neo4j?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have a table called "User and Review" in neo4j database. have to get those data from spring data neo4j. Here i do not want to get a modal. But I need a particular values. They are Id, message, rating etc. The problem is how to map those custom returned values from Db. please help me with it.

The sample query is:

```
@Query("MATCH (from:User)-[r:REVIEWED]->(to:User) where r.eventId={0} return ID(r),r.message,r.rating,r.eventId,r.zimId,from.firstName,to.firstName")
    public List<ReviewRelatioshipDto> getReviewsByEventIdAndId(Long eventId);
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/social] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Scalar response queries must only return one column. Make sure your cypher query only returns one item.] with root cause
java.lang.RuntimeException: Scalar response queries must only return one column. Make sure your cypher query only returns one item.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options- one is to use a [`@QueryResult`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_mapresult) and therefore, `ReviewRelationshipDto` must be annotated and follow JavaBean getter conventions or use `@Property`.

The other option is to just return a Map of columns and values `Iterable<Map<String,Object>>` where the key is the column alias and the value the column value.

Answer (score 0):

What Luanne mentioned with `@QueryResult` is probably the way to go.

However if you want an alternative pattern for dealing with persistence translation to a view model, what you can do is still populate your domain model (not your DTO) with spring data neo4j as you would nomally (in this case it would be something called `ReviewRelationship`). You would not have any DTO's mapped in this layer by the Spring Data Neo4j.

You can then select the fields you want into your DTO. You can do this yourself by feeding the domain object into a DTO builder or you can use something off the shelf like [Model Mapper](http://modelmapper.org/) and then pass this up to your view to be rendered.